# Replacing clipboard content

Tags: android, clipboard

How do I detect create a program that recognizes a certain string sequence and replace it with my own string

For example if a text string that begins with "a" is copied to clipboard it is then replace with "newString"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView txtV = findViewById(R.id.text);

    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clpData = ClipData.newPlainText("newText", txtV.getText());

    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clpData);

    if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString().startsWith("H")) {
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("newText", "newString"));
        Toast.makeText(this, clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have used a simple TextView as its string data source. You can manage this functionality with some event as well. Example: A textview with a blockquote when long pressed. It will work same except the way you are entering data into the clipboard manager changes. Cheers !!